# Load new page in function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

what I am trying to do is load a function in an anchor to change the page in jquery mobile

Here is the simplified HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="oldPage">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="newPage()">Link 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="newPage()">Link 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="newPage()">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="newpage">
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
     function newPage() {
       $.mobile.changePage('#newpage');
     }
```

But when I click the link I get the message "Error Loading page". How can I load a function to change to this new page, by clicking the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `href="javascript:newPage()"` but I do not recommend it

instead consider

```
<div data-role="page" id="oldPage">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#page1" id="someId1">Link 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#page2" id="someId2">Link 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#page3" id="someId3">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="newpage">
</div>

$(function() {
  $("#oldPage a").on("click",function() { 
    $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr("href"));
 });
});
```

I am guessing you mean

```
$(function() {
  $("#oldPage a").on("click",function() { 
    $("#oldPage").load($(this).attr("href"));
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong Instead of href you should use onclick event like

```
<li><a onclick="newPage()" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
```

coz href is basically used load or change to a page and also inside the function you have `preventDefault()` of the link so that the function alone will be executed not your link.